# changing slice colour of a pie chart in excel VBA

Tags: excel, charts, pie-chart, vba

Initially I wrote a function which changes the appearance of a series of pie-charts according to predefined colour themes

```
    Function GetColorScheme(i As Long) As String
Const thmColor1 As String = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Document Themes 14\Theme Colors\Blue Green.xml"
Const thmColor2 As String = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Document Themes 14\Theme Colors\Orange Red.xml"
    Select Case i Mod 2
        Case 0
            GetColorScheme = thmColor1
        Case 1
            GetColorScheme = thmColor2
    End Select
End Function
```

However, the paths are not constant and I would like to define each Pie chart slice on its own by an rgb colour. 
I found here on stackoverflow in a previosu topic ([How to use VBA to colour pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385213/how-to-use-vba-to-colour-pie-chart))  a way to change the colour of each slice of a pie chart

but I don't knwo how to implement the code into the function mentioned above. Could I potentially write

```
    Function GetColorScheme(i As Long) As String

    Select Case i Mod 2
        Case 0
            Dim clr As Long, x As Long

For x = 1 To 3
    clr = RGB(0, x * 8, 0)
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(x)
        .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = clr
    End With
Next x
        Case 1
            Dim clr As Long, x As Long

For x = 1 To 3
    clr = RGB(0, x * 8, 0)
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(x)
        .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = clr
    End With
Next x
    End Select
End Function
```

The function is linked to the main part of the script (which is)

```
For Each rngRow In Range("PieChartValues").Rows
chtMarker.SeriesCollection(1).Values = rngRow
ThisWorkbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Load GetColorScheme(thmColor)
chtMarker.Parent.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
lngPointIndex = lngPointIndex + 1
chtMain.SeriesCollection(1).Points(lngPointIndex).Paste
thmColor = thmColor + 1
```

where the line

```
 ThisWorkbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Load GetColorScheme(thmColor)
```

gets the value of the function  (see first bit of code - the original function) but now I don#t longer have the thmColor variable defined and don't knwo how to best implement the code into the function part

Answer (score 5):

Something like this (you'll need to adjust the colors to suit your needs)

http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm

```
Sub ApplyColorScheme(cht As Chart, i As Long)

    Dim arrColors

    Select Case i Mod 2
        Case 0
            arrColors = Array(RGB(50, 50, 50), _
                              RGB(100, 100, 100), _
                              RGB(200, 200, 200))
        Case 1
            arrColors = Array(RGB(150, 50, 50), _
                              RGB(150, 100, 100), _
                              RGB(250, 200, 200))
    End Select

    With cht.SeriesCollection(1)
        .Points(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = arrColors(0)
        .Points(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = arrColors(1)
        .Points(3).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = arrColors(2)
    End With

End Sub
```

Example usage:

```
chtMarker.SeriesCollection(1).Values = rngRow
ApplyColorScheme chtMarker, thmColor
chtMarker.Parent.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
```